# Cannot access Amazon EC2,My site is down

Tags: amazon-ec2

My Amazon ec2 instance is shown as running by AWS mgmt console.
However, I cannot ping the assigned IP nor connect via browser.
It has now been over 1 day.
I need some assistance to get my website available to the outside ASAP.
The instance number is  i-92812eff.My domain is http://www.say-cheese.com.
I cannot connect it through SSH and Filezilla Ftp.

Comment: Have you contacted Amazon support about this?

Comment: I can contact you site from the UK.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your site is up.  I'm able to access the web page.  Failing that you'll probably want to contact Amazon's support not a technical forum.